# How to setup VirtualBox port forwarding on Mac OS X to Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Everything I've read so far makes port forwarding sound like a snap but I must be missing some magic piece. Here's what I'm doing:

1. Host OS = Mac OS X
2. Guest OS = Ubuntu 16.04 Server
3. Run gunicorn web server on port 8000 on Guest OS
4. Forward port 8000 on Host (OS X) to 8000 on Guest (Ubuntu)

This is a fresh VM with no services configured and I've verified `ufw` is disabled. I can view 127.0.0.1:8000 within the guest OS but not from the host OS.

I am assuming my VirtualBox installation is simply missing a key step rather than the settings which look quite straightforward. Can anyone guide me the in the correct direction?

[image: Port Forwarding 8000 from Mac OS X host to Ubuntu 16.04 guest]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the application you are running is binding to `127.0.0.1`, which means it will only accept connections from the localhost.  Port forwarding is considered a remote connection.  You will need to figure out how to configure your application to accept remote connections or bind to either your VM's IP address or `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Thanks, I used `-b 0.0.0.0` on Gunicorn and now it works. This is not how I understood VirtualBox's NAT to work but at least it's working now